# OCaml comment containing "\" results in "comment not terminated"

Tags: escaping, ocaml

This comment is ok:

```
(* "\z" foo *)
```

This comment results in an error:

```
(* "\" foo *)
```

Is there a way to include a literal quoted single backslash in an OCaml comment? Why doesn't the obvious approach work? I would expect escapes in comments to simply be ignored.

For what it's worth, I'm trying to document tests for code that handles backslash escaping for its own purposes.

Thanks for reading.

Edit: The plot thickens. The following comments are acceptable:

```
(* "\" "\"    notice-> " *)
(* "\" "  "\"    notice-> " *)
(* "\" foo  "\" notice-> " " " *)
(* "\" " "  "\"    notice-> " *)
(* "\" "" "  "\"    notice-> " *)
(* "\" arbitrary "s  "\"    notice-> " *)
(* " \" note the spacing  " \"    notice-> " *)
(* "\" <- notice-> " *)
(* "\"  "  <- notice -> " " *)
(* "" *) (* """" *)
```

But add or take one at the ends, and it breaks. The following all fail (ask for more input in the REPL):

```
(* "\"  "\" *)
(* "\" foo  "\" notice->  *)
(* "\" foo  "\" notice-> " " *)
(* "\" foo "\" notice-> " " " " *)
(* "\" foo " "\" notice-> " "  *)
(* "\" foo " " "\" notice-> " "  *)
(* " *) (* """ *) (* """"" *)
```

I'm pretty lost. It seems like it's trying to balance quotes, but the escaped quotes throw it for a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments in OCaml must contain legal OCaml lexical units (tokens). This allows you to comment out code easily, even code with comments. Even code with string constants that happen to contain `(*` or `*)`.

You can have `"\\"` in a comment. But you can't have `"\"` because it's not a legal OCaml token. (It's an unterminated string constant.)

You can find the legal tokens of OCaml described in the [Lexical Conventions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html) chapter of the manual.

**Edit**

As lukstafi points out, it's much more correct just to say that strings appearing in OCaml comments must have the same structure as strings appearing outside comments. This is necessary to allow code (possibly containing string constants that look like parts of comments) to be commented out reliably.

**Edit 2**

```
(* "\" "\"    notice-> " *)
```

There's nothing surprising about this (in my opinion). The comment consists of two string constants with the `\` character between them. Outside of a string constant the `\` character doesn't quote anything. It's just a character. (In OCaml code `\` is not a legal character, but it's fine in a comment--note that lukstafi's clarification explains this.)

Maybe it will be clearer if I label all the characters. `(` for open quotes, `)` for close quotes, `Q` for backslash in a string (it quotes the next character), `B` for backslash outside a string (it's just an ordinary character), `S` for other characters in strings, `C` for other characters outside strings.

```
(* "\" "\"    notice-> " *)
  C(QSS)B(SSSSSSSSSSSSS)C
```

Here's one of the erroneous cases:

```
(* " *) (* """ *) (* """"" *)
  C(SSSSSSS)()C     C()()(SSS
```

It has an unterminated string constant. Note that the first string has two comment delimiter-like sequences in it. But it's just a string.

Comment: \" is a legal token, though. You put me on the right track, though, so thanks.

Comment: What kind of token is `\"`? Is it an identifier, an operator, a string...? (I claim it's not a legal token.)

Comment: It's the token you use to denote a literal quote in a string or char literal: [Lexical Conventions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html). Ctrl-F "character literals". The `escape-sequence` rule there is used again for string literals.

Comment: A construct inside a string constant isn't a token. The whole string constant is the token.

Comment: I don't agree with the claim that comments must contain legal tokens. The lexer for comments is a different, simplified one than the lexer for source outside comments. However, the lexer for comments recognizes string literals and uses the same lexing for them as is used for string literal tokens outside comments.

Comment: @lukstafi How does that explain the first example of my edit? The second escaped code should be outside any string, and the quote tacked on the end should start a new string. Either of those alone in a comment fail.

Comment: All of the examples in the first group have some number of complete string constants (2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3). All of the examples in the second group have some number of complete string constants plus an unterminated string constant (1+, 1+, 2+, 3+, 2+, 3+, 4+). A backslash outside a string constant is just a character like any other.

Comment: "A backslash outside a string constant is just a character like any other." *click* There it goes.